# How to change attributes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, setattribute

Good afternoon.
I've found great peace of code for my project. For states developer used data attribute manipulation in vanilla Javascript in order to change state.
Could someone help to translate plain JS to React

```html
 <div className='hero' data-nav="true">
    <main></main>

<header data-nav="true">
<nav>
  <div id="nav-links">
    <a className="nav-link" href="#">
      <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">Home</h2>
      <img className="nav-link-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1666091863721-54331a5db52d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80" />
    </a>
    <a className="nav-link" href="#">
      <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">Work</h2>
      <img className="nav-link-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1666055642230-1595470b98fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=995&q=80" />
    </a>
    <a className="nav-link" href="#">
      <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">About</h2>
      <img className="nav-link-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1666005487638-61f45819c975?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80" />
    </a>
    <a className="nav-link" href="#">
      <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">Contact</h2>
      <img className="nav-link-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1665910407771-bc84ad45676b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=776&q=80" />
    </a>
    <a className="nav-link" href="#">
      <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">Join Us</h2>
      <img className="nav-link-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553356084-58ef4a67b2a7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80" />
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>



<button id="nav-toggle" type="button" onClick={toggleNav}>
  <i className="open fa-light fa-bars-staggered"></i>
  <i className="close fa-light fa-xmark-large"></i>
</button>
    </div>
```

### JavaScript

```js
const toggleNav = () => {
  document.body.dataset.nav = document.body.dataset.nav === "true" ? "false" : "true";
}
```

### Part of CSS

```css
.hero[data-nav="true"] > main {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

nav {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}


header[data-nav="true"] > nav > #nav-links {
  transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
}

#nav-links > .nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Would love to hear clever solutions
Thank you

I've tried the event approach

```js
    const toggleNav = (event) => {
        event.target.setAttribute('data-nav', 'false')
    }
```

Comment: So do you want to know how to change attributes in React or do you actually want someone to "translate" that all into React? What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a simple use of **useState** and passing the value dinamically into the **data-someName** value.

Here an example:

```
  const [isNav, setIsNav] = useState(false);

  const toggleNav = (event) => {
    setIsNav((prevVal) => !prevVal);
  };

  return (
    <header data-nav={isDataNav}>
      <button id="nav-toggle" type="button" onClick={toggleNav}>
        ...
      </button>

      <nav>...</nav>
    </header>
  );
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

only difference is the html code writing in jsx format.
the jsx code showing below:

```
function Component() {
  const toggleNav = (e) => {
    e.target.dataset.nav = e.target.dataset.nav === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';
  }
  return <div className='hero' data-nav="true">
    <main></main>

    <header data-nav="true">
      <nav>
        <div id="nav-links">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">Home</h2>
            <img className="nav-link-image"
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1666091863721-54331a5db52d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80" />
          </a>
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">Work</h2>
            <img className="nav-link-image"
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1666055642230-1595470b98fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=995&q=80" />
          </a>
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">About</h2>
            <img className="nav-link-image"
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1666005487638-61f45819c975?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80" />
          </a>
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">Contact</h2>
            <img className="nav-link-image"
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1665910407771-bc84ad45676b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=776&q=80" />
          </a>
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            <h2 className="nav-link-label rubik-font">Join Us</h2>
            <img className="nav-link-image"
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553356084-58ef4a67b2a7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <button id="nav-toggle" type="button" onClick={toggleNav}>
      <i className="open fa-light fa-bars-staggered"></i>
      <i className="close fa-light fa-xmark-large"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
}
```